# How add variable from function to modelform

Tags: django

I try to transfer a new variable **urls** from a function to a ModelForm. 
In the letter, the variable comes, but in the form - saving an empty string.

**models.py**

```
class Order(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=25, verbose_name="Имя*")
    phone = models.CharField(max_length= 20, verbose_name="Мобильный телефон*")
    email = models.EmailField(max_length=25, verbose_name="Электронная почта*")
    text = models.TextField()
    urls = models.URLField()
```

**views.py**

```
def viewperson(request, slug):    
    trainer = Trainer.objects.get(slug = slug)
    urls = (reverse('trainers:viewperson', args=[slug]))
    if request.method == 'POST':
        model_form = ModelOrderForm(request.POST)
        if model_form.is_valid():
             subject = "New order"
        phone = model_form.cleaned_data['phone']
        name = model_form.cleaned_data['name']
        text = model_form.cleaned_data['text']
        email = model_form.cleaned_data['email']
        recipients = [mail@gmail.com']
        message = name + " "  +" "+ phone +  " " + "site.com"+urls +" "+ text

            if result['success']:
                try:
                    model_form.cleaned_data['urls']=urls #Here i try to send urls in forms urls-field 
                    instance = model_form.save()    
                    send_mail(subject, message, email, recipients)
                    return redirect('thanks_for_order')
                except BadHeaderError:
                    return HttpResponse('Invalid header found')
            else:
                messages.error(request, 'Error reCAPTCHA. Tray again.')
                return redirect('trainers:viewperson' , slug=slug)
    else:           
        model_form = ModelOrderForm()
    return render(request, "trainer_person.html", {'trainer':trainer,
                                                    'model_form':model_form,})
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understood your problem correctly you need to add url value to instance during save process. In this case you can use [`commit=False`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/forms/modelforms/#the-save-method) argument of form's save to update new instace before save it in DB:

```
instance = model_form.save(commit=False) 
instance.urls = urls
instance.save()
```

Comment: Excellent! This is exactly what I need